# How intercept ios rotation when physical device block is enabled (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I need to straight up the image taken by custom camera capture view but with physical device rotation block enabled it seem impossible.

[physical device rotation block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5k5v.png)

`UIDevice.current.orientation` works only with device rotation "unlocked". Someone can help me with this tedious bug? Thanks.

Comment: Please try to be little clear as to what you are asking. Use simple and clear English sentences please. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, next time I'll be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to unlock rotation while physical block enabled, but you can turn landscape mode as your main in project settings

[landscape mode as main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eU5B.png)

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I solved by accessing the device accelerometer directly